# с++ Реализация массива нуль-терминированных строк

Tags: c++

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать массив нуль-терминированных строк?
Я реализовал считывание строки:

```
char* get_string(){
    constexpr std::size_t initial_size = 4;
    char* buf = new char[initial_size];
    std::size_t used = 0,allocated = initial_size;
    std::cin >> std::noskipws;
    char c;
    while((std::cin >> c) && c!='.'){
        if(used+2 > allocated){
            allocated = allocated*3/2;
            char* new_buf = new char[allocated];
            for(std::size_t i = 0; i<used;++i)
                new_buf[i] = buf[i];
            delete[] buf;
            buf = new_buf;
        }
       buf[used++] = c;
    }
    std::cin >> std::skipws;
    if(!std::cin){
        delete[] buf;
        buf = nullptr;
    }else{
        ++used;
        buf[used-1] = '.';
        buf[used] = '\0';
    }
    return buf;
}
```

Задача состоит в том, чтобы организовать массив, в который идет запись таких строк.

Comment: Суть вопроса не понятна. Какие у вас возникают с этим проблемы?

Answer (score 2):

Массив из 3-х строк

```
char *a[] = {(char *)"str1", (char *)"str2", (char *)"str3"}; // в С можно опустить приведение типа `(char *)`
```

либо

```
const char *a[] = {"str1", "str2", "str3"};

#define ASIZE(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof((x)[0])) // макрос для количества элементов в таком массиве
```

В вашем случае (после появления примера кода) можно либо сделать динамический массив `char **da`, который надо дополнять новыми элементами (указателями, которые возвращает `get_string()`) абсолютно аналогично тому, как Вы в своей функции строите строку, либо использовать готовый класс `vector`.

```
#include <vector>

....
vector<char *> v;  // вектор указателей 
char *s;

while (s = get_string())
  v.push_back(s); // добавим новую строку в конец вектора

// распечатаем все строки
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
  cout << v[i] << '\n';
```